# league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 get custom metada

Tags: metadata, flysystem, thephpleague

I'm messing with the flysystem library (it is amazing, anyway!)
I created some files on the remote s3 bucket defining some custom metadata

```
$conf = [
'visibility' => 'public',
'Metadata'     => [
    'Content-type' => 'image/jpeg',
    'Generated' => 'true'
]];
$response = $filesystem->write('/test/image.jpg', $image_stream, $conf);
```

**'Generated' => 'true'** is a custom metadata and I can find it in AWS Bucket's console.

I'm not able to read the custom metadata "generated" on **filesystem** resource after

```
$allFiles = $filesystem->listContents('/path/', true)->toArray();
```

##UPDATE 1

I understood that I should use the "getWithMetadata" plugin as explained In the documentation: https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/v1/docs/advanced/provided-plugins/#get-file-info-with-explicit-metadata

It seems pretty easy, but it seems there is not any League\Flysystem\Filesystem::addPlugin() method in my src.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to use the S3 FlySystem adapter you need to init the S3 client

```
$client = new Aws\S3\S3Client($options);
```

In S3 SDK you could use

```
$allFiles = $filesystem->listContents($path)->sortByPath()->toArray();

$file = $allFiles[0];
$headers = $client->headObject(array(
"Bucket" => $bucket,
"Key" => $file->path()
));

print_r($headers->toArray());
```

to get the list of all file's metadata!